# Field member error

Tags: java

Okay, I might be going crazy but I've never encountered this error before.

This doesn't compile:

The error I get is : "Cannot find symbol variable visited"

**EDITED**

Here's the whole function:

```
public void depthFirstTraverse(Node startNode) {
    Stack<Node> myStack = new Stack<Node>();
    myStack.push(startNode);

    while (!myStack.empty()) {
        Node top = myStack.pop();
        top.visited = true;
        System.out.println(top.item);
        for (int i = 0; i < top.getAdjList().size() ; i++) {
            //Node temp = (Node)top.getAdjList().get(i);
            if (!(Node)top.getAdjList().get(i).visited) {
                myStack.push((Node)top.getAdjList().get(i));
            }
        }
        top.visited = false;
    }

}
```

This part doesn't work

```
if (!top.getAdjList().get(i).visited) {  // this line gives me an error
```

This does:

```
for (int i = 0; i < top.getAdjList().size() ; i++) {
            Node temp = (Node)top.getAdjList().get(i);
            if (temp.visited) {
                myStack.push(temp);
            }
        }
```

Why is this so?

Comment: What's the error message? Where is `top` declared? We need a lot more info to help you.

Comment: there is no variable called temp in your first example `myStack.push(temp)`

Comment: sorry for the lack of information -- i edited it, and made it make more sense

Comment: What's "getAdjList"? You cast calls to its "get" everywhere else.

Comment: it just returns a linkedlist of nodes, nothing more

Comment: Also said "you cast it everywhere else". That's the important part.

Comment: I've tried casting it, and not casting it. It just won't recognize the visited field member without my assigning it to the "temp" variable

Comment: ... Because you cast temp to a Node.

Comment: Also, if you don't do an @-reply, the person you're talking to won't be notified of your response.

Comment: @DaveNewton , I understand that I cast temp to a Node in the latter case (the working one). However, I'm confused as to why top.getAdjList().get(i).visited wouldn't work whether casted or not.

Comment: @DaveNewton the only difference between the two, is that I assign getAdjList().get(i) to a variable.

Comment: Because it's not a Node until you make it one-it's probably an Object before the cast. You don't show the code I asked about, so that's a guess.

Comment: Oh, the line you said doesn't work isn't the actual source-I focused on the line you called out theater than the one buried in the whole function; very confusing to mix things up like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (!(Node)top.getAdjList().get(i).visited)` looks like you're trying to cast a `boolean` to a `Node`

perhaps try this instead:

`if (!((Node)top.getAdjList().get(i)).visited)` which does the cast then checks the `visited` property

Comment: HA! Wow. That was it. Thanks a lot, pal. What a dumb mistake